Bake to target with SimpleBake is too pixelated
I'm using the SimpleBake addon to bake from a few higher poly pieces to a single lower poly model, but for some reason the results are more pixelated than they should be.
I started off baking at 4k to a 4k texture, I did the UV unwrap and packed everything as best I could, only to find the results don't look good at all. I looked at the images of the bakes (specifically normal map) and saw they were very pixelated. It's almost as if it's being baked at 1k or something and then saved as 4k.
Original
vs
Baked 4k

I tried upping the bake resolution, and it improves the result some, but it's still not entirely acceptable and I've hit the memory limits of my PC at 12k bake and save to 4k.
Normalmap 4k and baked at 4k
vs
Normalmap 4k baked at 12k

I've fiddled with every setting I can think of, but I must have missed something. This is the first time I've had this kind of problem baking things to one target or baking higher to lower poly up until now.
Simplebake settings:

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing this problem?
Thank you in advance.
Blender 4.1.1 and SimpleBake up to date.
